# rake db:migrate not working with Mysql adaptor ( windows 7 )

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am an experienced PHP programmer who is trying his hand on "Ruby on Rails", I have windows 7 as my operating system , I have installed ruby (1.9.3p125), rails (3.2.1) and gem (1.8.16), rake (0.9.2.2).

I am following the documentation on rails site to work on a demo app .

I created new project using "rails new demoApp". then inside the project I created a scaffold and tried

```
rake db:create
```

this created a database with no tables in it

Then I tried to migrate my db using

```
rake db:migrate
```

here is where my prompt freezes and does nothing , i mean according to my assumption it should have created tables of my project along with an additional table named "schema_migrations" in mysql but nothing happens.can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong ?

I googled for the log I received after using trace command the log says

```
Rake Aborted !!
Mysql::Error: query: not connected: SHOW TABLES LIKE 'schema_migrations'
```

i tried

```
rails dbconsole
```

it connects easily to the mysql prompt so there is no connection issue I dont know what is happening can anyone tell me where am I going wrong ?

I hope I am clear about my question.

Thanks

Comment: I hope this info. can help you http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=34012

Comment: Nope no help already added the libmysql.dll file , that is the reason why it could create the database, also the link provided for possible solution on that forum points to the titanium app server. Thanks for the help @thesis

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the MySql gem? https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql

If not, add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'mysql'
```

This gem is important because it sets your database up with Active Record, the ORM for Rails.

Comment: Ya, I have already included that, I was able to create database, Migrations are the problem

Comment: Hmm, how about trying adding a model like say user with 

'rails g scaffold user name'

to create a user migration among other files and seeing if it works. Sometimes without creating a table, rails may have trouble finding the database. I do not believe schema_migrations is necessarily a table, but more or less a file keeping track of creating tables and adding/subtracting columns from those tables.